# Send custom header with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to send a custom value in the request header with Jquery to my Web API. This is my script:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://localhost:61190/webapi',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    headers: {
          'mykey':'value',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
});
</script>
```

When I read the request header in the web API, it looks like this:

**Connection\r\nAccept\r\nAccept-Encoding\r\nAccept-Language\r\nHost\r\nUser-Agent\r\nAccess-Control-Request-Method\r\nOrigin\r\nAccess-Control-Request-Headers\r\n**

And I cannot find mykey value with the header. I read the header in the the Gobal,aspx

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
string keys = "";                        
        for (int i = 0; i < HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Count; i++)
        {
            keys += HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Keys[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        throw new Exception(keys);
}
```

When I use fiddle the web API receive the custom key.

Comment: Can you double-check in your browser, if your request-headers are with your request, or not.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: Then you can press F12, click on network and retry your request.

Comment: I can see nothing. When I use fiddler the web API gets the custom key.

Comment: Do you use Ajax as standalone or do you also have Jquery, Angular or another JavaScript-Framework, that can manipulate the request?

Comment: I use Jquery to call $.ajax

Comment: Did you mind my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you intercept the options-call.
If you didn't throw an Exception, but log the headers to a Output or a logfile, would show you, that with the second call, the real Post request the headers are well added.
The options-request is because of the cross-origin call.

Update 3:
What I would try: Filter only POST

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("POST")==true)
    {
       string keys = "The count of headers is: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Count.ToString() + "  values: " + Environment.NewLine;                        
       for (int i = 0; i < HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Count; i++)
       {
           keys += HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Keys[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
       }
       // don't throw this Exception, if the request is of Type Options.
       throw new Exception(keys);
    }

}
```

Comment: I added these lines but they did not work:
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />      
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />

Comment: It's no Cors-issue. I just saw you make a cross-origin-call. If you have a cross-origin-call, the application first sends a options-request, to check if the service returns a 204. After the response, the Post-request is sent. But if you catch the options-request and throw an Exception, there never will be a post-request.

Comment: How can I send or catch the whole request then?

Comment: I'm not very used to Asp.net with global.asax. I'm more used to Asp.net Core. Maybe you could catch only calls of Type POST.

Comment: @Niklaus Thanks. The web API returns empty string, I think this means that my JS code is sending nothing to the Web API

Comment: @DainaHodges Next try, to check the count of headers.

Comment: The headers count is 9 headers

Comment: This is funny and there is still no key added?

Comment: No, this is the result: 

"keep-alive\r\n*/*\r\ngzip, deflate, br\r\nen-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6,lt;q=0.4\r\nlocalhost:61190\r\nMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36\r\nGET\r\nnull\r\nauthorization,content-type,x_csrf_token\r\n"

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod I get when I run my script is Options not post or get

Comment: @DainaHodges This is what I told you. If you run a Asp.Net-App and make a cross-origin request, then the app first does a Options-call to the webAPI, to check if the request can be done at all. If the options-Call is answered with 204, the real Request is started. If you intercept the options-call, the real request never will start. If you instead ignore Options as Http-Method, the next request, which is not of type Options is intercepted. I think the next problem was, that a get-request is also intercepted before your post-request. So you have to reduce your method to http-Method POST.

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: Did you see the third Update of my answer?

Comment: And what's the result?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one for headers & change values as per your requirement.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://SOMEAPI.p.mashape.com/', // The URL to the API. You can get this in the API page of the API you intend to consume
    type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method, can be GET POST PUT DELETE etc
    data: {}, // Additional parameters here
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { console.dir((data.source)); },
    error: function(err) { alert(err); },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "YOUR-MASHAPE-KEY"); // Enter here your Mashape key
    }
});
```

Comment: I got an error:
Failed to load http://localhost:61190/webapi: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Comment: I'm connecting to that web API from my local PC, maybe this is the problem